# Yandex-Tank TLS запросы

Tags: ssl, яндекс-танк, tls

Можно ли настроить танк для соединений работающих с TLS протоколом? Я нашел возможность в фантоме указать использование TLS протокола при подключении. `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` Параметр необходимо передать в командную строку во время запуска фантом. Как это сделать в танке - я не смог найти.

[Ссылка на тикет в фантоме про TLS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12165)

Текущая конфигурация фантома танка.

```
[phantom]
address=%(env_url)s:443
ssl=1
writelog=1
rps_schedule=step(1, 70, 5, 15s) line(1, 70, 1m)
header_http=1.1
uris=/
```

Answer (score 2):

При установке TLS коннекта клиент и сервер обязаны выбрать максимальную общую версию. То есть если openssl на машине с танком и мишень поддерживают sslv3,tls1.1,tls1.2 - будет использоваться tls1.2.

См. [установка коннекта в phantom](https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/blob/master/pd/ssl/ssl.C#L132) и [описание функции SSLv23_client_method](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSLv23_client_method.html)

Опция ssl=1 говорит только что нужно использовать шифрование.

PS: у нас используется не phantomjs

Comment: Я пробовал выполнить запросы на цель через curl с --verbose флагом. Он показал, что используется tls1.2. Когда я принудительно включал в curl использование ssl любой версии, выводились ошибки, либо завершения tls шифрования, либо не поддерживаемости соединения. Могу поделиться линкой на цель для проб.

Comment: в фантоме не надо явно указывать версию протокола - по rfc, во время установки коннекта между клиентом и сервером (в вашем случае phantom и GCloud) автоматически выберется самая новая версия. То что у вас не получилось принудительно использовать ssl с curl скорее всего говорит что сервер уже не поддерживает эту версию протокола.

Comment: Вы можете запустить танк и параллельно снять tcpdump к мишени и посмотреть как устанавливается коннект. Вам нужен пакет с ServerHello - в нем будет указаны и версия протокола и cipher suits итд выбранные сервером на основании того что передал phantom в ClientHello

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624745/capture-only-ssl-handshake-with-tcpdump

Comment: Почему я и говорил про curl и принудительный ssl. Я проверил логи фантома и там ошибка ssl connection error 5. На сколько я вычитал - это на уровне шифрования ошибка. То есть, мне кажется, что проблема все еще в неправильной версии ssl

Comment: нужно смотреть в tcpdump, смотреть как именно устанавливается tls соединение. Можете выгрузить его куда-нибудь?